# Project level Culture setting for Azure Functions App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to change culture on a project level on Azure Functions App?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings

The app is using Consumption plan or Premium plan, not via ASP.NET Core.

My `Startup.cs` file is like below:

```
  public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
       }
}
```

Can ASP.NET Core that is based on different `Startup.cs` **not** like above use Consumption plan or Premium plan??

Asp.net Core that must use App Service plan like below:
https://andrewlock.net/adding-localisation-to-an-asp-net-core-application/

Comment: Can you explain about what you what clearly? I can not understand...

Comment: Is it possible to change culture on a project level on Azure Functions App?

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?

Comment: There might be no built-in support atm.

Answer (score 7):

When migrating legacy application running on servers to Azure you always need to take care of Timezone and Culture settings that originally are fetched from the machine. For Azure Functions you can set the timezone in the app settings:

```
WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE=Europe/London
```

Possible values found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones. This actually differs for app services that seem to use TZ for Linux and WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE for Windows.

For culture it is more complicated. Using aspnet core you define it in Configure in the Startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, 
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(cultureInfo),
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                cultureInfo,
            },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                cultureInfo,
            }
        });
    }
```

That is not possible in Azure Function Apps. What you can do is to create a Setup class and then set the culture for the appdomain and the current thread. This will probably work as long Azure isnt altering the Appdomain.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder app)
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` delegates to `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, so you only need to set the latter (or the former, if you want to allow threads to explicitly opt into an explicit culture upstream).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Function didn't provide a built-in method to change culture.

Put this at the starting of your function app:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

//......

string culture = "en-US";
CultureInfo CI = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CI;
```

Above code will change the culture to `en-US`. You can set it to other value.

This is the document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1

Does this solved your problem?

Comment: That is the solution I am using. But this is not a built-in method by Function App.

Comment: another question, will this work even for async/await. that is, multiple threads reads the same method consecutely.

Comment: @Pingpong No, there isn't a built-in methond to change the culture in azure function app.  I still can't understand your problem. It seems that you want to change the culture through the hosting plan? If this is the case, I need to remind you that plan is only a means of virtual machine resource allocation, and it does not affect culture. The change of culture needs to be based on code. There is no such built-in method in azure function.

Comment: @Pingpong Azure function didn't provide a built-in method to change the culture. Can we end this question now?:)

Comment: Sure, I will leave it open for now, which would be answered when it is available.