# Enforcing culture in all Azure Function calls not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to enforce a specific culture (EN-US) across the board in an Azure Function

To do this I have a base class

```
public class MyFunction
{
    protected void EnforceCulture(string culture = Cultures.UK)
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture, false);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    }

    protected async Task<IActionResult> ExecuteWithAuthorization(HttpRequest req, Func<Task<IActionResult>> func)
    {
        if (req.Unauthorized())
        {
            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
     
        //Request is authorized so enforce culture and call logic
        EnforceCulture(Cultures.USA); 
        return await func();
    }
}
```

I use this in my function by the logic below

```
    [FunctionName("my-function")]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyFunctionAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "my-route")]
        HttpRequest req)
    {
        var response = await ExecuteWithAuthorization(req, async () =>
        {                
            var result = new MyResult()
            {  
              Test = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
            }

            var okResult = (IActionResult)new OkObjectResult(result);
            return okResult;
        });

        return response;
    }
```

When I look at result.Test, I would expect it to show the date as a USA date given that I have forced the culture to be USA, but its shown as UK

What am I doing wrong?

I think the issue may be that the await operation runs on its own thread which may not have its info (i.e. culture) derived from the main thread.  If that's the case how do I fix this?

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions won't provide built-in method to change culture need to put the below code in [starting of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture?view=netcore-3.1)

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

//......

string culture = "en-US";
CultureInfo CI = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CI;
```

For Azure Functions you can set the [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the app settings:

```
WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE=America
```

For Functions need to create startup class with the below code

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder app)
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

For further reference check the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62709543)